# larave: how to remove slected data from foreach loop when count reach given value

Tags: sql, laravel, foreach, laravel-8

**Over view**

am working with appointment booking system but time slots are open for all there are no limit for booking I want to hide/disable selected time slot when booking count reaches 25 for selected time slots

here is my variable for use  foreach

```
@php
$times = DB::table('times')
->where('app_id', $app->id)
->get();
@endphp
```

and am foreach like this

```
@foreach ($times as $item)
@php

$blocktime = DB::table('bookings')->where('app_id',$app->id)
->where('time',$item->time)
->where('status',1)->get();
@endphp

<div class="col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                            
<label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
<input type="radio" name="time" value="{{ $item->time }}">
<span>{{ $item->time }}</span>
</label>

</div>
@endforeach
```

in this variable `$blocktime` i calculate how many booking is made for a selected time slot when

```
$blocktime  == 25
```

when `$blocktime` count reaches 25 I want to disable that particular time slots how can I do that?

Thank you for your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can get from your question, you need to *not displaying* `time` that alredy has 25 `booking`

You just need use `count()` instead of `get()` and then use `continue` if greater than 24

```
@foreach ($times as $item)
@php

$blocktime = DB::table('bookings')->where('app_id',$app->id)
->where('time',$item->time)
->where('status',1)->count();

if ($blocktime > 24) {
    continue;
}
@endphp

<div ....>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I haven't test the code, hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand regarding your query is that you want to disable the radio button contains a time slot if $blocktime = 25, so you can do something like the below to achieve this :

```
    @foreach ($times as $item)
    @php
    $breakTime = false;
    $blocktime = DB::table('bookings')->where('app_id',$app->id)
    ->where('time',$item->time)
    ->where('status',1)->count();
    if ($blocktime == 25) {
        $breakTime = true;
        continue;
    }
    @endphp
    
    
    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="{{ $item->time }}" {{($breakTime == true) ? 'disable' : ''}}> 
    <span>{{ $item->time }}</span>
    </label>
    
    </div>
    @endforeach
```